# Как сделать активным пункт меню соответствующий блоку в фокусе при скроле страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Во время скрола по странице нужно подсвечивать пункт меню который соответствует блоку в фокусе. 
Как отслеживать элемент который на экране в фокусе ?
  И как его связать с пунктом меню?

Пример разметки [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewUA/r6ug4m01/2)

```
   <section id="one" class="scroll"></section>
    <section id="two" class="scroll"></section>
    <section id="three" class="scroll"></section>
    <section id="four" class="scroll" ></section>
    <section id="five" class="scroll"></section>
    <section id="six" class="scroll"></section>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#two"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#three"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#four"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#five"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#six"></a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/rishabhp/pen/aNXVbQ?editors=0010

Comment: @MaximLensky, ваш пример - это ответ на мой вопрос, пожалуйста оформите его как ответ , а не как коммент и я его помечу как правильный!Спасибо!

Comment: это же с codepen там даже автор есть - отвечать не буду - главное решена задача